# How to allow multiple entries to have the same slug?

Tags: craft3, entries, sections, slug

Users create an account and their profile (**domain.com/userName**) is a template pulling info from craft users.

Each user can create entries, all stored in a Structure section (**domain.com/userName/entrySlug**).

Problem is when different users have an entry with the same title, entrySlug can become entrySlug-1 etc.  Although the URL is unique, the slug obviously can't be with entries in the same structure.

But I cannot think how to set this up. A structure per user seems overkill.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a custom route to resolve `domain.com/userName/entrySlug`?

Comment: @Oli Yea entry URI format  `{author.username}/{slug}`

Comment: That's odd, when I try locally, I'm not getting duplicate slugs. Which version of Craft are you on? Are your users creating entries via the Control Panel or a front-end entry form?

Comment: That's the problem - not getting duplicate slugs. Say I have user1 and user2, they both might create an entry with the same title. So one of those users will get an entry slug of entrySlug-1. Would like entry slugs to be unique to the user, not all users.

Comment: Again, I'm not seeing the same thing as you. User A creates entry *about*, URI is `userA/about`, if user B creates an *about* entry, URI is `userB/about`. Now if user A creates another *about* entry, then the URI is `userA/about-1`. Are you testing via the Control Panel?

Comment: Now I feel incredibly stupid. I was only testing a duplicate entry under 1 user and immediately went down a rabbit hole when I saw the potential problem. Thanks for getting me out!

Comment: Glad you're sorted!